# change jquery step validation-wizard finish button into a submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i am using jquery-steps, i would like to change the finish button from a  
to a proper submit button. Where do i change that.

i have tried doing it this way, but the css is then getting broken.

```
<form action="admin/practitioners" class="validation-wizard wizard-circle">
{{csrf_field()}}
<!-- Step 1 -->
<h6>Step 1</h6>
<hr/>
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="wlocation2"> Title : <span
                            class="danger">*</span>
                </label>
                <select class="custom-select form-control required"
                        id="wlocation2" name="title_id">
                    <option value="">Select Title</option>
                    @foreach($titles as $title)
                    <option value="{{$title->id}}">{{$title->name}} 
                    </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

here is my jquery

```
<script>
    $('.validation-wizard').steps({
        headerTag: "h6",
        bodyTag: "section",
        transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
        enableFinishButton: !1,
        onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
            if (currentIndex == 3) {
                var $input = $('<input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit Data"/>');
                $input.appendTo($('ul[aria-label=Pagination]'));
            } else {
                $('ul[aria-label=Pagination] input[value="Submit"]').remove();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

I expect that when i get to the last step it display a submit button on finish not a link. Right now its still displaying the finish button with broken css

Comment: So does your CSS works? Have you tried `<button type="submit">`?

Comment: where should i change this button type="submit"

Comment: In your JS `var $input = $('<input type="submit"...`

Comment: The JavaScript is not working too